# Memory Leak with DateTime objects?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

I am having issues with a memory leak which I believe is caused by DateTime objects. My code is receiving an integer from a client, creating a DateTime object, generating an integer out of that object, comparing it to what the client sent, and sending that data back. This happens every 1000ms, when the client sends a request for it's ping.

Client-side Code:

```
private void sendPingRequest()
{
    List<byte> payloadData = new List<byte>();
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    int seconds = now.Second;
    int ms = now.Millisecond;
    int totalMs = (1000 * seconds) + ms;
    payloadData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)26));
    payloadData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(4));
    payloadData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(totalMs));
    client.GetStream().Write(payloadData.ToArray(), 0, payloadData.Count);
    return;
}
```

Server-side code: (after the tcplistener reads all of the data)

```
private void handlePing(byte[] data, TcpClient sender)
{
    int pingRequest = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    int seconds = now.Second;
    int ms = now.Millisecond;
    int realMs = (1000 * seconds) + ms;
    int diff = realMs - pingRequest;
    List<byte> backData = new List<byte>();
    backData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)27));
    backData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(4));
    backData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(diff));
    sender.GetStream().Write(backData.ToArray(), 0, backData.ToArray().Length);
}
```

When the server receives one of these ping requests and sends data back, the total memory of the application slowly starts increasing, and exponentially increases in speed.
[image: Visual Studio Debugger]

Thanks, any help solving this is much appreciated!

Comment: List<byte> backData = new List<byte>(); - declared above the three blocks.
it is the byte[] which the socket is writing back to the client.

Comment: Have you tried (just for playing at least) to perform a full GC ? (third generational GC) let's say every 10nth request. The ideea is that in server mode i know that GC behaves a little bit differently and objects collection is more relaxed for gaining performance.

Comment: Why do you assume there is a memory leak? The GC might not have kicked in yet.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Visual Studio deubugger shows it, and at one point (before I implemented a force-crash on this) the application's memory climbed to 6gb and crashed my workstation.

Comment: @GeorgeLica do you mean via `GC.Collect();`? In that case, yes, I have tried it and it did not work.

Comment: Is this all your server side is doing?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov my server-side is handling requests to send a file every 8ms or so. However, if I comment out the client-side operation to send ping requests, the memory leak never happens. It only occurs when the server-side is receiving ping requests.

Comment: The methods look fine. Have you tried replacing them with sending fixed packages without any logic? I suspect the problem might be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @GeorgeLica did not fix, the memory still jumped up to 1.2gb :\

Comment: @nvoigt Interesting catch, that is proving true. Issue persists when DateTime is not referenced at all, only using integers. I'll have to investigate more, thanks!

Comment: Sound like you aren't closing a stream to me. Have you considered using a memory profiling tool to check the instances that the GC root can see? I'm willing to bet it's bad programming than an issue with the framework

Comment: @Charleh Yes, but.. do not rush to  bet.

Comment: Your `totalMs` does not measure total milliseconds, If your `DateTime.UtcNow` on the client was taken at 1:45:59.000 PM and the server was taken at 1:46:01.000 PM You would have `totalMs == 59000` and `realMs == 1000` creating a `diff == -58000` or negitive 58 seconds instead of the real value of 2 seconds. Just send `now.Ticks` across the wire instead. HOWEVER!!! Your ping is still not that good because it requires the system clocks to be exactly in sync to the millisecond which is not a reasonable expectation.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the stream you get will not be closed when you close the client.

Depending on your general handling, if this function is the only function operating on the TcpClient's stream, you should probably close it. Maybe even use a `using` block:

```
var stream = sender.GetStream();
stream.Write(backData.ToArray(), 0, backData.ToArray().Length);
stream.Close();
```

or

```
using(var stream = sender.GetStream())
{
    stream.Write(backData.ToArray(), 0, backData.ToArray().Length);
}
```

Comment: After looking into this more, the memory leak is still occurring even if no code is executed upon receiving the data from the client. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely a memory leak causes by a DateTime object. Generally, if an object is not Disposable and doesn't have event subscriptions (to a long lasting instance) it shouldn't be the root cause for a memory leak. Having said that you really need a proper tool (eg: [RedGate Memory Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough)) to analyze memory leaks.

The code you have provided is not enough to say anything about the memory leak. However, keep in mind you MUST dispose all Disposable objects when you don't need them any more. Use 'using' when you are creating a local disposable object, it will dispose the instance when it is going out of the scope. Specially when you are using any kind of streams it is the best practice to wrap them within a using clause. It will close it and dispose for you([dispose actually closes the stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422(v=vs.110).aspx) when disposing).

So, yes. Try disposing all disposable objects and test again. 'backData' object looks suspicious to me. Make sure you clear or dispose it appropriately.